# Problem cause with libxml2 after upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade, software-center, empathy

After upgrade 12.04 64bit LTS to ubuntu 14.04 64bit LTS have problems with libxml2.

Can't run software center,empathy etc

```
# software-center
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
   from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 106, in <module>
   from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.panes.installedpane import InstalledPane
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/installedpane.py", line 34, in <module>
   from softwarecenter.db.categories import (CategoriesParser,
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 30, in <module>
   import lxml.etree as ET
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lxml/etree.so)
```

or

```
# empathy
empathy: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1)
```

Did

```
# locate libxml2.so
/opt/openoffice4/program/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/lib/lib/libxml2.so.2/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-vmrc/5.1/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/vmware-vmrc/5.1/lib/libxml2.so.2/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.1
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2
/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.8.0
```

or

```
# sudo dpkg --list | grep libxml2
ii  libxml-libxml-perl       2.0108+dfsg-1                                       
ii  libxml2:amd64            2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3                              
ii  libxml2:i386             2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3
ii  libxml2-dev:amd64        2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3
ii  python-libxml2           2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.3        
ii  python-lxml              3.3.3-1ubuntu0.1                                    
ii  python3-lxml             3.3.3-1ubuntu0.1
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libxml-libxml-perl

Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 208
Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20901, but runtime libxml2 is older 20800
update-perl-sax-parsers: Registering Perl SAX parser XML::LibXML::SAX with priority 50...
Warning: program compiled against libxml 209 using older 208
Warning: XML::LibXML compiled against libxml2 20901, but runtime libxml2 is older 20800
update-perl-sax-parsers: Updating overall Perl SAX parser modules info file...
Replacing config file /etc/perl/XML/SAX/ParserDetails.ini with new version
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading debian squeeze to jessie, and then further to unstable. The problem is, that you have an old version of libxml2 library in your **local** folder `/usr/local/lib`.

You most likely have the correct version installed by your package manager in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`, however library in local folder has a higher priority and in the end is the one that is loaded.

If all my assumptions are correct, you should be able to resolve by running the following by root:

```
# mv /usr/local/lib/libxml2* /
```

Then try to run empathy or other applications that were experiencing problems. If everything works fine, you can delete unused old libraries by running:

```
# rm -f /libxml2*
```