openconnect: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxmlsec1.so.1: undefined symbol: xmlIOFTPRead, version LIBXML2_2.4.30
I have installed openconnect by:
sudo apt install openconnect

Then I'm calling it by:
echo MyPassword | openconnect --pfs mydomain.com:8442 -u MyUsername

But the following error is thrown:

openconnect: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxmlsec1.so.1: undefined symbol: xmlIOFTPRead, version LIBXML2_2.4.30

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Related
Maybe related: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/75721
Also, related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2139849
Maybe this might solve my problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/532234/507217

Why are you making comments and showing links in your own question? If they are possible answers you should be following up on this, not posting them. As for what are your options that is not a comment, edit the question and add it there please.

Inspired by
Inspired by this: https://askubuntu.com/a/532234/507217
Also that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/715484/158683
Wrong library loaded
ldd command showed that libxml is being loaded from /usr/local/lib/:
ldd /usr/sbin/openconnect

libxml2.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007e27259a9000)

Solution
The error is resolved by forcing to load it from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:
echo MyPassword | LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 openconnect --pfs mydomain.com:8442 -u MyUsername

